# Can't I use nil for 'undefined' on parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am making a simple app, and implementing the userInformation part. The user can edit his info, but I have trouble that if user doesn't put any info, it will crash when I try to retrieve data from an undefined column.

This is my code to retrieve the user data.now I can check a specific value, but still, I got a error with 'undefined' one.

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "Note")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kg8KhAWCms", block: {
        (obj, error)in
        if let obj = obj! as? PFObject {




            let nickname = (obj.objectForKey("text")) as! String



            if (nickname != nil) {

///// I have a error message that binary operator'!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'NiLiteralConvertible'




                self.nickNameLabel.text = nickname

            }else{
                self.nickNameLabel.text = "you don't have a nick name"
            }


        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

what is the 'NiLiteralConvertible' ?
and I've tried this as well,

```
   var query = PFQuery(className: "Note")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kg8KhAWCms", block: {
        (obj, error)in
        if let obj = obj! as? PFObject {




            let nickname = (obj.objectForKey("text")) as! String


            if !(nickname.isEmpty) {
                self.nickNameLabel.text = nickname

            }else{
                self.nickNameLabel.text = "you don't have a nick name"
            }


        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

So I am asking how can I handle retrieving undefined value before crash? (please write full code for me)

///like this

```
if (undefined in parse  == somekindOfType) {



print("yes")



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `nickname != nil` because you have already said that it **cannot** be `nil` with `let nickname = (obj.objectForKey("text")) as! String`.

The `as! String` unwraps the `obj.objectForKey("text")` and at which it cannot be `nil` or you will get an error.

I suggest using the following:

```
if let nickname = obj.objectForKey("text") as? String {
    self.nickNameLabel.text = nickname
}
else{
    self.nickNameLabel.text = "you don't have a nick name"
}
```

Perhaps this would be beneficial to read: [Swift Literal Convertibles](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/)

Comment: perfectly works!! I waited this answer so long. Ty!!